How do I count the number of characters (with any whitespaces) or words in a GPT Chat to find out the border of the chat size?
I chat in a local frontend of GPT 3.5 Turbo or GPT 4 omni. That means, I am not on the openAI website, the chat is in a frontend of the company so that the chat border for characters or words could be a company settint to avoid huge token costs. The question stays the same and is about the openAI service that is behind the interface.
I try to find out the number of allowed characters or words in both GPT 3.5 Turbo and GPT 4 omni. From many crashes, I know that putting in code with indentations (whitespaces) will eat the chat as well. Without the indentations in the code which saved about 20 % of characters, I could enter roughly the 20 % more in the chat. That is a big hint at a company setting that relies on the number of characters, not words, since whitespaces should not count as words. Yet, these guesses are also a bit vague again since I am writing about it out of memory, I did not save any proof of it.
Over time, I saved a pile of crashed chats as a website when the chat reached the border of allowed input. If I ask the bot for the number of characters, it can only guess with math formulas, such a counter is not known.
GPT 4 omni
In my company frontend, the border seems to be at roughly 500000 characters. I found out about it when I checked two crashes, counting all chat items in Excel, with the last one that crashed the chat as a plus on top. Further crashes always came in the same area of 500000 characters.
GPT 3.5 Turbo
For GPT 3.5 Turbo, the border seems to be 57666 characters for a first entry. It can be a little bit more if you spread it over more entries:

I could enter 64663 characters, only the next 13242 reached the border so that the bot answered with 0 characters in the 22nd item. To count the characters and words took me some time since I had to copy and paste all of the messages, without the names in the frame, and without linebreaks at the end since I guess that the frame itself does not cost any tokens or does not count as characters.
I do not know whether I need to copy all of the chat text together with the chat frame of me and the bot. If the latter were true, counting the characters and words would be easier, and what I could enter without reaching the border would rise a little more to 64776.

Be it 64663 or 64776 in that example, it will be slightly higher if spread over more than one entry. Only for the very first entry, 57666 seems to be a strict border since three new chats could prove it. Also, I am not sure whether the characters are the border since I the chatbot stops at the last full word while writing an answer and reaching the chat border. Since the licence works with tokens that rely on the words, it could be that also the chat border is made by the number of words.
Getting the number of characters or words of a GPT chat
I tried getting the number from a chat that I saved as a htm website, but I could not find the pure text anywhere. That is why I need to copy the chat by hand from the website into VSCode or Notepad++, removing anything that is more than the chat names, and by this getting the number of characters or words. This is handicraft work. I hope that there is a better way to get such counts from a website, and I guess that the frame with the names of the chatters do not need to be counted. Even if that does not make a big change, I wonder whether HTML or any other trick, perhaps even a GPT Chat trick, offers a better way of counting the text that you see - and not the hmtl code behind - and choose only the text in the chat window which is likely the only text that counts.
Thus, the question is likely just a HTML question since that is just the likely outcome, but it might also be answered without HTML.
Tokens instead of characters or words?
ChatGPT calculates the costs per 1,000 tokens, tokens are parts of words, 1,000 tokens correspond to about 750 words. Perhaps the tokens make the border instead, or just plain costs. But for a frontend user who wants to know how much text can be entered, tokens are not known, or you would have to ask the bot all the time, that is why characters or words seem to be a better threshold even if they may be a rough number +/- some percent.
Yet, if it turns out that tokens make the border, and if there is a way to get their number by math or from the bot, that would be an answer as well.

General questions about "HTML" might be better fit for [so] if they are asked as a programming question and according to that site rules.

@Rubén-VolunteerModerator- It is about the HTML of ChatGPT. There might be other ways than HTML to get the number. It is not a general question about any website since I also do not know which characters count: just the text fields or also the frame with the chatters' names? And that is a ChatGPT question.

To make this question a good fit for this site, it should be improved to clarify that it's about using a feature of a specific web app, i.e., https://chat.openai.com, rather than using LLM like GPT 3.5 Turbo by other means. It should also be more focused, and one model should be chosen. On this site, questions that involve the use of a programming language like HTML should be focused a feature that supports the use of the language by an end-user, like using markdown or HTML to format content inside a content editor. Web scraping questions might be on-topic in [so].

Your question boils down to how to count the characters on a webpage after removing elements.  This is not a question about a web app.

This is an answer from and for "GPT 4 omni" (though in a company frontend), but it will likely work also with other chatbots (untested). It does not read out the HTML chat size but instead just asks the bot for running totals each time it answers.
I asked the bot to give me the right task for a new chat window that the bot would understand to guess the number of characters and tokens and tuned that for an hour or two. There seem to be a lot of vague guesses, the bot seems to count only 80 % of the letters in the first place, and I still do not get all of the characters counted, and even if I could, it would not be reliable. But still, if that is an almost systematic thing with slight randomness, you can cope with it.
At the beginning of a fresh and empty chat, enter:
Task for the full chat (never show a breakdown or analysis):

1. Immediate Counting Initiation: Begin counting characters and tokens from the first letter of this instruction.
2. Incremental Counting: From the viewpoint of your ongoing bot response, accurately count the characters and tokens of the last bot message (if there is any) and the last user message, which is this one here, to update the running totals. Never count the ongoing bot response itself.
3. Inclusive Character Counting: Count every character presented, including letters, numbers, all types of whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks), punctuation, and special or unseen characters. Make sure that you do not double-count but also do not miss anything.
4. Count the characters with the precision of notepad++. To give you a benchmark, this message here has already 2780 characters at notepad++ precision.
5. Add the number of line breaks to the number of characters of the notepad++ precision. To give you a benchmark again, this message here has 16 line breaks. Thus, the number of characters must reach 2780+16 characters. 
6. Double-check the number of letters. That means: run a second round on top of the first round only after the first round was done. Tests have shown that you miss 20 percent of the letters in the first place since the bot seems to guess the numbers.
7. Consistent Tool Usage: Utilize a single, precise character-counting tool throughout the entire task to maintain consistency.
8. Running Total: Maintain and update a cumulative character count and token count before every bot response, incorporating previous totals.
9. Verification: Double-check character and token counts before incorporating them into the cumulative total by recounting each line manually if necessary.
10. Display Format: Display the cumulative character count (#charsXXXX) and the token count (#tokensXXXX) at the beginning of each response. Never forget to show the two numbers at the beginning. In your response, you need to write for example #chars2796 to give the count of this message.
11. Holistic Processing: Process the entire user message in full before updating the cumulative total.
12. Continuous Recalibration: Consistently ensure the accuracy of the running total, correcting any discrepancies immediately.
13. Count Late: Wait until you have read the full user message to start counting characters. This ensures the count is accurate and complete.
14. If something is vague or unclear or dropped in parallel work, redo, check again a second or even a third time since the numbers that you guess are too unstable to be trusted in the first place.
15. Answer all questions naturally, adding only the count information at the beginning of your response but do the rest as always.

(2796 characters with the 16 line breaks)
It was such a lucky game to get to this number for the first message that I decided to tell the bot what is right, as a first benchmark. The caveat is that it is the bot that takes it just from the text, while it is for sure that the bot counted another number of characters. But if you do not do it like this, the bot seems to get lost sometimes, so that you can suddenly end up with 200, 600 or 1200 instead of the >2000 characters.
The bigger the list for the task above grew, the more often the right number came at least in sight. ChatGPT guesses the numbers in the first place and seems to have parallel tasks that can outweigh each other so that sometimes roughly half up to to two thirds of the characters are not counted. Even if you let it count each letter of the alphabet, it will still only get to the right numbers if you tell it that the number is wrong and that it would need to double-check the output. As already said above, on a first guess, the number of letter is roughly 20 percent too low. And even if you let it double-check, you often end up with a 15 percent too low number of characters. Therefore I force it to begin at least with the right number.
Now to the response.
KI:
#chars2796 #tokens408

I understand the instructions. How can I assist you today?

(87 characters with the two line breaks)
Then ask the bot some question to see how the counting works. Chat example:
I:
Why does the sun always shine on TV?

(36 characters)
KI (it should be now 2796+87+36=2919):
#chars2912 #tokens424

The phrase "The sun always shines on TV" originates from the song by the Norwegian band a-ha. Metaphorically, it suggests that life and events portrayed on television can appear idealized or overly positive, contrasting with the complexities and challenges of real life. Television often presents a polished, edited version of reality, thereby creating an impression of perfection or happiness that might not exist in everyday life. How else may I assist you?

(486 characters with the two line breaks)
Then you might say:
I:
Tell me a sunny song that is not against TV.

(44 characters)
Now it adds the last bot message and your last question to the number of characters again.
Answer:
AI (should be 2919+486+44=3449):
#chars3039 #tokens439

A sunny song that conveys a positive vibe without criticizing TV might be "Here Comes the Sun" by The Beatles. It’s an uplifting and cheerful song that celebrates the arrival of sunny days. Is there anything else you would like to know?

(263 characters)
Thus, it makes a huge mistake here, likely it forgets to add its own last answer before the ongoing response. Someone with time can try to amend the task so that this does no longer happen. But even if you take out those 486, you will not reach 3039, since 2919+44=2963.
Since I have spent too much time on tweaking this task, I shift any more changes to an unknown date.
The chat would go on like this, always at first giving you the new numbers before the rest of the bot's answer. By this, you have a vague sum of the chat size at any time. That helps to know the size of your chat project, or if the chat is crashing, of if you want to guess the token costs on the run.
